# add 11:59 value to react-datepicker options

Tags: reactjs, intervals, react-datepicker

I'm using react-datepicker for a single daytime value
how to enter code here` display the time to be like this code

```
` [
{ label: '6:00 PM' },
{ label: '6:30 PM' },
{ label: '7:00 PM' },
{ label: '7:30 PM' },
{ label: '8:00 PM' },
{ label: '8:30 PM' },
{ label: '9:00 PM' },
{ label: '9:30 PM' },
{ label: '10:00 PM'},
{ label: '10:30 PM'},
{ label: '11:00 PM'},
{ label: '11:30 PM'},
{ label: '11:59 PM'},
```

]`

starting with 12 am with interval 30 but I need to add 11:59 to the values like the example